# Upload file fragment by FTP

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy, delphi-xe6

I need to develop a backup application for my company, saving files to an FTP server. From what I researched, I can use the TIdFTP component of the Indy library.

I was analyzing here, and I noticed that some files, especially database files, are more than 10GB in size.

My question is: Is there any way that if a connection problem occurs, the file copy restarts from where it left off?
 Without having to restart from scratch?

I am using Delphi XE6.

Answer (score 7):

The FTP protocol has a `REST` command for resuming broken file transfers.

Indy's `TIdFTP` component has `ACanOverwrite` and `AResume` parameters on its `Get()` method, and `AAppend` and `AStartPos` parameters on its `Put()` method. Use these parameters for resuming broken transfers.

The `TIdFTP.ResumeSupported` property tells you if the server supports the `REST` command (most FTP servers do).